# Why Hello World is not showing up?

Tags: reactjs

This is the same code as from the youtube tutorial,
but it's not working for me:

Hello World is not showing up in the browser.

```
import React from 'react';

function myComponent() {
  return(
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
  );
}

class App extends React.Component {
   render(){
    return(
      <myComponent/>
    );
   }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: What *did* happen in the browser?  What is the HTML you're using?  Is there an error on the browser's debugging console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You must define a component name started by a capital letter. It's the rule of React (https://en.reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html)

> User-Defined Components Must Be Capitalized When an element type
>   starts with a lowercase letter, it refers to a built-in component like
>    or  and results in a string 'div' or 'span' passed to
>   React.createElement. Types that start with a capital letter like  compile to React.createElement(Foo) and correspond to a component
>   defined or imported in your JavaScript file.
>
> We recommend naming components with a capital letter. If you do have a
>   component that starts with a lowercase letter, assign it to a
>   capitalized variable before using it in JSX.

2) You must insert a enclosed div or React.Fragment for MyComponent in render() of AppComponent/>.

```
function MyComponent() {
  return(
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
  );
}

class App extends React.Component {
   render(){
    return(
      <div> // OR <React.Fragment>  OR <>
        <MyComponent/>
      </div> // OR </Fragment>  OR </>
    );
   }
}
```

Comment: @DigoXin : If it helps you, please validate and vote my answer ! It motivate us give you answers.