# Buttons not rendering on Codepen using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, codepen

I'm trying to make a calculator using React but i can't get what's in the render to display on the page.
It was showing up with just the "display" div.

```
class Calculator extends React.Component{ 
  render(){
    return (  
        <div className="display">test</div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Calculator />, document.getElementById("calculator"));
```

Then i added the buttons and it stopped displaying

```
class Calculator extends React.Component{ 
  render(){
    return (  
        <div className="display"></div>
        <div className="numRow">
            <button id="one">1</button>
            <button id="two">2</button>
            <button id="three">3</button>
        </div>
        <div className="numRow">
            <button id="four">4</button>
            <button id="five">5</button>
            <button id="six">6</button>
        </div>
        <div className="numRow">
            <button id="seven">7</button>
            <button id="eight">8</button>
            <button id="nine">9</button>
        </div>
        <div className="opRow">
            <button id="add">+</button>
            <button id="subtract">-</button>
            <button id="multiply">*</button>
            <button id="divide">/</button>
        </div>
        <div className="etcRow">
            <button id="clear">Clear</button>
            <button id="decimal">.</button>
            <button id="equals">=</button>
        </div>
  ); 
}}

ReactDOM.render(<Calculator />, document.getElementById("calculator"));
```

I've added React, ReactDOM and Babel.
https://codepen.io/hanuruh/pen/dyPxRNX

Comment: You could view my answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/59923480/4386148

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Hello World is not showing up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59923432/why-hello-world-is-not-showing-up)

Answer (score 3):

```
class Calculator extends React.Component{ 
  render(){
    return (  
      <>
        <div className="display"></div>
        <div className="numRow">
            <button id="one">1</button>
            <button id="two">2</button>
            <button id="three">3</button>
        </div>
        <div className="numRow">
            <button id="four">4</button>
            <button id="five">5</button>
            <button id="six">6</button>
        </div>
        <div className="numRow">
            <button id="seven">7</button>
            <button id="eight">8</button>
            <button id="nine">9</button>
        </div>
        <div className="opRow">
            <button id="add">+</button>
            <button id="subtract">-</button>
            <button id="multiply">*</button>
            <button id="divide">/</button>
        </div>
        <div className="etcRow">
            <button id="clear">Clear</button>
            <button id="decimal">.</button>
            <button id="equals">=</button>
        </div>
      </>
  ); 
}}

ReactDOM.render(<Calculator />, document.getElementById("calculator"));
```

Every React Component should have one parent element.

Comment: oh okay, sorry for such noob question

Answer (score 2):

([Link to fixed codepen](https://codepen.io/hanuruh/pen/dyPxRNX)).

In JSX, normally, you should return a single DOM element. So all your content should be wrapped in a single div (or some other element).

```
render(){
    return (
        <div>
            ALL YOUR CONTENT HERE
        </div>
    )
}
```

Another solution is to use [`React.Framgent`](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) instead. You can return several DOM elements if those are wrapped in `React.Fragment`. This is useful because it avoids adding new meaningless divs:

```
render() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <ChildA />
      <ChildB />
      <ChildC />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

You can use the [short syntax](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#short-syntax) for fragments like such:

```
render() {
  return (
    <>
      <ChildA />
      <ChildB />
      <ChildC />
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add a `wrapper` to your code or a `<Fragment>`, check the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) for more information. your code probably having error because of that.

```
class Calculator extends React.Component{ 
  render(){
    return (
       <div>
        <div className="display"></div>
        <div className="numRow">
            <button id="one">1</button>
            <button id="two">2</button>
            <button id="three">3</button>
        </div>
        <div className="numRow">
            <button id="four">4</button>
            <button id="five">5</button>
            <button id="six">6</button>
        </div>
        <div className="numRow">
            <button id="seven">7</button>
            <button id="eight">8</button>
            <button id="nine">9</button>
        </div>
        <div className="opRow">
            <button id="add">+</button>
            <button id="subtract">-</button>
            <button id="multiply">*</button>
            <button id="divide">/</button>
        </div>
        <div className="etcRow">
            <button id="clear">Clear</button>
            <button id="decimal">.</button>
            <button id="equals">=</button>
        </div>
     </div>
  ); 
}}

ReactDOM.render(<Calculator />, document.getElementById("calculator"));
```